# Hightchart x-axis to top

Tags: jquery, highcharts

For my project i made an Highchart chart. Works well but on the bottom and top there is a lot of space. I've fixed that by setting yAxis min on 0. But there is still some space above the xAxis.

Does somebody know the solution for this problem?

**Screen:** 2500 should be the top..
[image]

**Code:**

```
$('#yeardiagram').highcharts({
    chart: {
        events: {
            redraw: function(event) {
                getMonthProfit();
            }
        }        
    },  
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },                  
    title: {text: 'Kosten jaaroverzicht', x: -20 },
    subtitle: { text: 'Verdeeld naar budget',x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Januari', 'Februari', 'Maart', 'April', 'Mei', 'Juni',
            'Juli', 'Augustus', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: { text: 'Kosten' },
        min:0,
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: { valuePrefix: '€' },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: data                
});
```

Comment: Try set min/maxPadding as 0 on yAxis http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.maxPadding

Comment: Thanks! That is the solution. You can put your comment as an answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try set min/maxPadding as 0 on yAxis http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.maxPadding